# python3 logger - UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a logger setup like this:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
import sys

# root logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# create a file logger
handler = RotatingFileHandler('log/core-application.log', maxBytes=1024*1024*1, backupCount=3)
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(funcName)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)


# create stdout logger
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(funcName)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.info('Logging all setup')
```

On my development system this logging entry is working ok. It logs what you see here:

`logger.info('message key: {}'.format('2018-10-19_00:20:56_\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xb5\xd9\x88\xd8\xa7\xd9\x81/'))`

The same line on my ubuntu AWS EC2 server gives me an error:

> --- Logging error --- Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/**init**.py", line 982, in emit
>       stream.write(msg) UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 108-113: ordinal not in range(128)

Can anybody image why this is?

btw:
EC2 server locales are:

`LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`
`LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

What worked for me is adding encoding='utf8' arg to the handler :

```
 formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
 log_path = '/var/log/app'
 log_file = '%s/%s.log' % (log_path, name)
 create_log_file(log_file)
 handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file, encoding='utf8')
 handler.setFormatter(formatter)
 logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Answer (score 8):

I just found the solution and would like to share the answer:

It was connected to supervisor controlling the python app on the server.
Somehow supervisor config needs to contain the environment variables below to be able to print UTF-8 to stdout.

```
[supervisord] 
environment=LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8',LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
```

edit:

https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html#whatsnew37-pep538

Python 3.7 seems to be designed to automatically solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

After having searched for a long moment, this solution worked for me under Windows 10 x64 with Python 3.7.6, whenever a `logger.error('message', exc_info=True) would fail because the traceback contained invalid characters.

Adding a u before the formatter string to force an unicode message:

```
#formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(funcName)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
formatter = logging.Formatter(u'%(asctime)s - %(funcName)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
```

Hope it helps whoever may read this.

Comment: This does not make sense. In Python >= 3.3, `u"..."` is exactly the same as `"..."`, the `u` is practically a no-op. See https://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/strings.html#string-literals.